# Javascript Slot Machine Bug?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm coding at the moment a kind of Slot Machine in JS and PHP.

I found a script online which was running with 3 "Items".

So now I added a few more but its counting only to the Number for and not all Numbers which are defined in the Reel Array ? ...

My Question is why?

Here is my Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
    requestAnimationFrame polyfill
*/
(function(w){
    var lastTime = 0,
        vendors = ['webkit', /*'moz',*/ 'o', 'ms'];
    for (var i = 0; i < vendors.length && !w.requestAnimationFrame; ++i){
        w.requestAnimationFrame = w[vendors[i] + 'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        w.cancelAnimationFrame = w[vendors[i] + 'CancelAnimationFrame']
            || w[vendors[i] + 'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!w.requestAnimationFrame)
        w.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element){
            var currTime = +new Date(),
                timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime)),
                id = w.setTimeout(function(){ callback(currTime + timeToCall) }, timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!w.cancelAnimationFrame)
        w.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id){
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
})(this);

/*
    Slot Machine
*/
var sm = (function(undefined){

    var tMax = 3000, // animation time, ms
        height = 210,
        speeds = [],
        r = [],
        reels = [
            ['1',  '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'],
            ['1',  '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0'],
            ['1',  '2',  '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0']
        ],
        $reels, $msg,
        start;

    function init(){
        $reels = $('.reel').each(function(i, el){
            el.innerHTML = '<div><p>' + reels[i].join('</p><p>') + '</p></div><div><p>' + reels[i].join('</p><p>') + '</p></div>'
        });

        $msg = $('.msg');

        $('button').click(action);
    }

    function action(){
        if (start !== undefined) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            speeds[i] = Math.random() + .5; 
            r[i] = (Math.random() * 3 | 0) * height / 3;
        }

        $msg.html('Spinning...');
        animate();
    }

    function animate(now){
        if (!start) start = now;
        var t = now - start || 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            $reels[i].scrollTop = (speeds[i] / tMax / 2 * (tMax - t) * (tMax - t) + r[i]) % height | 0;

        if (t < tMax)
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        else {
            start = undefined;
            check();
        }
    }

    function check(){
        $msg.html(
            r[0] === r[1] && r[1] === r[2] ?
                'You won! Enjoy your ' + reels[1][ (r[0] / 70 + 1) % 3 | 0 ].split(' ')[0]
            :
                'Try again'
        );
    }

    return {init: init}

})();

$(sm.init);
</script>
```

I don't get where the error is or where it could be?

It's only showing in the single wheels the number 1-4, but not 0-9 
which is a must.

Which part did I oversee?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your for loop to count to the max in the array, you have to tell it to do so. Currently you still have it coded to stop before 3, so that's what it does.

Comment: I changed the counter up to 10 and now its totally bugged i must click everytime again to move the Wheels a bit ... 
But too again only showing numbers 1-5